# Saving/loading data in Unity

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

I have been messing around with saving and loading in Unity in which I save a serialized class to a file.  I have a Serializable class :

```
[Serializable]
class Save
{
    public List<int> ID = new List<int>();
    public List<int> Amounts = new List<int>();
}
```

and save it to a file A-OK.  I can load it with no errors but if I wanted to add later :

```
[Serializable]
class Save
{
    public List<int> ID = new List<int>();
    public List<int> Amounts = new List<int>();
    public int extra = 0;
}
```

and I run my scripts it gives me a deserialization error which I completely understand as when I cast the deserialized file to my new class 'Saved' the new variable I added doesn't exist and it gives me the error.

I found this error when I was fixing an Asset in the store and I know one fix can be just change the filename so a new file is created but I don't just want to wipe the contents of what was saved before.

So my question is, if I wanted to add more variables to my serialized class how would I catch and adjust to old versions of it if people were to update the asset?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a known problem and I believe this has been answered many times on this site. I just can't find the duplicate question on this site but you can solve this by using Json and PlayerPrefs. You can always add or remove items without any error. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3785314) is an example using Json..

Comment: I agree with @Programmer JSON is definitely better than serialization.

Comment: @Programmer Ok cool, So based on what I linked above I am using the ONE DATA way of doing it.  When I do JsonUtility.ToJson() I get a string as a return.  Do I then serialize that string (and put in a file) or what would you use to have that information in that string be saved so if the user turns off the game and back on I still have that info saved somewhere?  If I end up adding more to my class Save would I just do JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite()?  Sorry if I am asking too many Q's but I feel I am very close to solving my problem which in all honestly seems very simple.

Comment: Check my answer. Maybe it made things clear.

Comment: Never trust the serialization system of Unity3D. It's buggy! I would rather write (de)serializer myself just as what Programmer suggested.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This problem is known when using C# serializer. Convert the data to Json with `JsonUtility` then save it with the `PlayerPrefs`. When loading, load with the `PlayerPrefs` then convert the json back to class with `JsonUtility`.

Example class to Save:

```
[Serializable]
public class Save
{
    public List<int> ID = new List<int>();
    public List<int> Amounts = new List<int>();
    public int extra = 0;
    public float highScore = 0;
}
```

**Save Data**:

```
void Save()
{
    Save saveData = new Save();
    saveData.extra = 99;
    saveData.highScore = 40;

    //Convert to Json
    string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveData);
    //Save Json string
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("MySettings", jsonData);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

**Load Data**:

```
void Load()
{
    //Load saved Json
    string jsonData = PlayerPrefs.GetString("MySettings");
    //Convert to Class
    Save loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<Save>(jsonData);

    //Display saved data
    Debug.Log("Extra: " + loadedData.extra);
    Debug.Log("High Score: " + loadedData.highScore);

    for (int i = 0; i < loadedData.ID.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("ID: " + loadedData.ID[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < loadedData.Amounts.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Amounts: " + loadedData.Amounts[i]);
    }
}
```

Difference between `JsonUtility.FromJson` and `JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite`:

**A**.`JsonUtility.FromJson` creates new Object from Json and returns it. It allocates memory.

```
string jsonData = PlayerPrefs.GetString("MySettings");
//Convert to Class. FromJson creates new Save instance
Save loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<Save>(jsonData);
```

**B**.`JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite` does **not** create new Object. It has nothing to do with adding more datatype to your class. It just overwrite the data that is passed in it. It's good for memory conservation and less GC. The only time it will allocate memory if when you have fields such as `array`, `string` and `List`.

Example of where `JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite` should be used is when performing constant data transfer with Json. It will improve performance.

```
//Create Save instance **once** in the Start or Awake function
Save loadedData = null;
void Start()
{
    //loadedData instance is created once
    loadedData = new Save();
}

void Load()
{
    string jsonData = PlayerPrefs.GetString("MySettings");
    //Convert to Class but don't create new Save Object. Re-use loadedData and overwrite old data in it
    JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(jsonData, loadedData);
    Debug.Log("High Score: " + loadedData.highScore);
}
```

Comment: Thank you once again Programmer for yet another detailed explanation that made this as easy to understand as learning my abc's.

Comment: You are welcome. You can encrypt the json data before saving it to make it hard for players to tamper the saved data. Just Google "C# string encryption". You shouldn't worry about that but some do. Happy coding!

Comment: I was just about to ask about the safety of saving the json data through player prefs.  You're a god damn mind reading genius Programmer.

Comment: Lol not safe at all. But encryption will make it safer. See [here](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_encrypt_decrypt_using_asymmetric_algorithm_rsa) for simple encrypt and decrypt function. Feel free to ask new question if you are not able to get it working with that. Although the information on that link is very easy to understand with the amount of example they provided.

Comment: This is for you Programmer : https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/3b/ba/18/3bba18ea0b75ca4df2bd69d01c5f785d.jpg.  I failed at shortening it :(

Comment: another million!!

Comment: i wish i could give a million bounty!

Comment: I just freaked out because I saw +100 then I looked and  saw where it came from. Thanks once again.

Comment: another million for `FromJsonOverwrite`