# PlayerPrefs not saving on Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I ran into a bit of a problem with PlayerPrefs in unity3d 5.4. (I am using 5.4 because there is a game-breaking bug in 5.5.)

Here is the code:

```
void OnApplicationQuit() {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("numerator", numerator);
}
```

This works fine in the editor, but on mobile it's a different story. It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`PlayerPrefs.Save`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html) after `PlayerPrefs.SetInt`. That will likely solve your problem.

```
void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("numerator", numerator);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

If that does not solve your problem, do the save operation in the [`OnApplicationPause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) or `OnDisable` function.

```
void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
{
    if (pauseStatus)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("numerator", numerator);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

If both of these fail, Please [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965645/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-game-state/40966346#40966346) here for how to use Json to save and load game data.

Comment: Thanks! The `OnApplicationPause` along with the `PlayerPrefs.Save` did the trick!