# Save and Load Facebook user access token

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I know this is a silly question but how can I easily save the user access token after a user logs in?

Here is a part of my code that is triggered by a button:

```
public class FacebookLogin : MonoBehaviour {


void Awake()
{
    if (!FB.IsInitialized)
    {
        FB.Init(InitCallback, OnHideUnity);
    }
    else
    {
        FB.ActivateApp();
    }
}

private void InitCallback()
{
    if (FB.IsInitialized)
    {
        FB.ActivateApp();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
    }
}

private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
{
    if (!isGameShown)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}

public void FBLogin()
{
    List<string> perms = new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" };
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
}

private void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
{
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;

        FB.API("/me?fields=first_name", HttpMethod.GET, getName);
        FB.API("/me/picture?type=square&height=128&width=128", HttpMethod.GET, getProfilePic);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Main_Menu");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
    }
}

private void getName(IResult result)
{
    LocalDataBase.Name = result.ResultDictionary["first_name"].ToString();
}

private void getProfilePic(IGraphResult result)
{
    LocalDataBase.profilePicture = result;
}
```

}

Thank you in advance for all your answers.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it is not allowed .. need some research..

Comment: The token i want to save is                                                                       
var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;

Comment: It's a Facebook.Unity.AccesToken . My problem is that is not syncronizable so i cannot save it normally.

Comment: Sorry. What do you mean by not  syncronizable? Any example?

Comment: Serializable* sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the token by making a custom serializable class that wraps around all the variables inside Facebook's `AccessToken` class. This custom class should contain a function that can  be used to convert its data into Facebook's `AccessToken` class.

You can then save and load that custom class as Json.

Grab `DataSaver` class from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966346/3785314) post to simplify saving and loading the data. We will call our custom class `FaceBookToken`.

**Your Facebook Token:**

```
var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
```

**Save**:

```
FaceBookToken faceBookToken = FaceBookToken.createFaceBookToken(aToken);
DataSaver.saveData(faceBookToken, "FB_Token");
```

**Load**:

```
FaceBookToken loadedFaceBookToken = DataSaver.loadData<FaceBookToken>("FB_Token");
//AccessToken loadedToken = loadedFaceBookToken.toAccessToken(); //OR
AccessToken loadedToken = loadedFaceBookToken;
```

**Apply Loaded Data**:

```
Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken = loadedToken;
```

Don't know if applying it is possible or allowd but it seems to compile without problems.

**Delete**:

```
DataSaver.deleteData("FB_Token");
```

---

The `FaceBookToken` custom class:

```
[Serializable]
public class FaceBookToken
{
    public static AccessToken CurrentAccessToken;
    public DateTime ExpirationTime;
    public DateTime? LastRefresh;
    public IEnumerable<string> Permissions;
    public string TokenString;
    public string UserId;

    //Function that let's you easily create new instance of FaceBookToken from AccessToken
    public static FaceBookToken createFaceBookToken(AccessToken currentToken)
    {
        FaceBookToken faceBookToken = new FaceBookToken();
        FaceBookToken.CurrentAccessToken = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
        faceBookToken.ExpirationTime = currentToken.ExpirationTime;
        faceBookToken.LastRefresh = currentToken.LastRefresh;
        faceBookToken.Permissions = currentToken.Permissions;
        faceBookToken.TokenString = currentToken.TokenString;
        faceBookToken.UserId = currentToken.UserId;
        return faceBookToken;
    }

    //Converts our custom FaceBookToken to AccessToken
    public AccessToken toAccessToken()
    {
        AccessToken loadedToken = new AccessToken(TokenString, UserId,
            ExpirationTime, Permissions, LastRefresh);
        return loadedToken;
    }

    //Converts our custom FaceBookToken to AccessToken(Implicit Cast)
    public static implicit operator AccessToken(FaceBookToken currentToken)
    {
        AccessToken loadedToken = new AccessToken(currentToken.TokenString, currentToken.UserId,
             currentToken.ExpirationTime, currentToken.Permissions, currentToken.LastRefresh);
        return loadedToken;
    }
}
```