# Store values to the android device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am creating inventory system for my game and problem is that i need to create system to store multiple values to my device.

I know there are `PlayerPrefs` but with that i can only store 2 values (let's say key for one and value for second), but i need something like table. So i have to store something like this in single line:

```
inventorySlot
itemID
amount
```

this is simple 3 size value, but also i would need to store 4, 5, or more.

So how can i achieve this?

Here is current code where problem is that storing to json is not working. Look at comment at the end of Debug.Log to see what it displays.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InventoryModel
{
    public List<InventoryItem> InventoryItems;

    public InventoryModel()
    {
        InventoryItems = new List<InventoryItem>();
    }
}

public class InventoryItem
{
    public int inventorySlot;
    public int itemID;
    public float amount;
}


public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int inventorySlots = 5;

    public Text itemSlot1;

    void Start ()
    {
        AddItemToInventory(1, 0, 2000);
        LoadInventory();
    }

    void Update ()
    {

    }

    public static void AddItemToInventory(int slot, int itemID, float amount)
    {
        InventoryModel im = new InventoryModel();
        InventoryItem ii = new InventoryItem();
        ii.inventorySlot = slot;
        ii.itemID = itemID;
        ii.amount = amount;

        im.InventoryItems.Add(ii);

        foreach(InventoryItem ia in im.InventoryItems)
        {
            Debug.Log(ia.itemID + "-" + ia.amount + "-" + ia.inventorySlot);    //Display 0-2000-1
        }
        string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(im);
        Debug.Log(jsonString);                                                  //Display {}
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerInventory", jsonString);
    }

    private void LoadInventory()
    {
        foreach(InventoryItem ii in LoadInventoryFromPref().InventoryItems)
        {
            //Doesnt enter this loop
            Debug.Log(ii.inventorySlot);
            Debug.Log(ii.itemID);
            Debug.Log(ii.amount);
            Debug.Log("====");
        }
    }

    private static InventoryModel LoadInventoryFromPref()
    {
        string test = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerInventory");
        Debug.Log(test);                                                        //display {}
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<InventoryModel>(test);
    }

    private static int GetMaxInventorySlots()
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("MIS"))
        {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MIS");
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does “not working” mean? Use your debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar answer was provided here [What is the best way to save game state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965645/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-game-state) that uses `DataSaver.saveData`.

Use `PlayerPrefs` to store a `JSON` instead of individual keys. 
As long as the data is less than 1MB in size, `PlayerPrefs` is the best option.

Since all you wish to store is an array of:

```
inventorySlot
itemID
amount
```

You can do the following:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "inventorySlot": 1,
      "itemID": "123ABC",
      "amount": 234
    },
    {
      "inventorySlot": 2,
      "itemID": "123ABC",
      "amount": "554"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then store that in `PlayerPref` by assigning it to a key of your choice using [setString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetString.html)

You can then utilize Unity's [JsonUtility](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) to serialize/deserialize the JSON.

The Model (**Note**: Decorate models with `[System.Serializable]`:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class InventoryModel
{
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public int inventorySlot;
    public string itemID;
    public int amount;
}
```

Here's a full example:

```
    InventoryModel invModel = new InventoryModel();

    Item model = new Item();
    model.inventorySlot = 1;
    model.itemID = "123ABC";
    model.amount = 234;

    Item model2 = new Item();
    model2.inventorySlot = 2;
    model2.itemID = "123ABC";
    model2.amount = 554;

    invModel.Items.Add(model);
    invModel.Items.Add(model2);

    //Generate JSON then save it
    string yourModelJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(invModel);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("InventoryKey", yourModelJson);

   //Read JSON back to Model
   InventoryModel testModel = new InventoryModel();
   string rawJsonFromPref = PlayerPrefs.GetString("InventoryKey");
   testModel = JsonUtility.FromJson<InventoryModel>(rawJsonFromPref);
```

Comment: @Downvoter When you downvote, add a comment so that we know why there was a downvote. It helps me improve the answer.

Comment: I do not know why anyone downvote anything since here you are getting free advices. Anyway it looks totaly ok to me and i will try it tomorrow. I didn't know about JSON so i will tell you tomorrow hwo it was

Comment: Not me but why do people feel the need to answer a duplicate? I mean this question has been asked many times and you should know that by doing a quick search. Also, remove `{get; set;}`. That wouldn't work.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks, I fixed the `{get;set;}`, the question marked as duplicate uses a different approach though - `DataSaver.saveData` instead of what my answer covers `PlayerPref.SetString`. I will include that answer 's url in mine for reference.

Comment: Both questions are asking the-same thing. That answer mentioned  `PlayerPrefs` twice and provided a link for another solution that uses that. It did not use `PlayerPrefs` on purpose but instead used `File.WriteAllBytes`. It's the-same process....Convert to Json then save.

Comment: @Programmer Fair enough, would it best for me to delete this answer then?

Comment: You don't have to. You may have to do a quick search before adding answers. It looks like the downvote is out so I put an upvote.

Comment: @Programmer I will make sure to do that, thanks again.

Comment: @Dayan for some reason it gives me null error at `JsonUtility.ToJson`. Here is my [code](https://pastebin.com/4x4XFdQX)

Comment: when i print ii it has values but for some reason inventory model is not adding it

Comment: Fount out, i should have initialized `InventoryItem` list inside `InventoryModel`

Comment: But still for some reason i can not read it :/

Comment: @AleksaRistic Updated the answer, see if it helps read the saved data. If not, let me know if you encounter an exception. Use `Debug.log` to see the data from the object and such.

Comment: When i print json string before i store it to pref it print `{}` and i guess that is empty?

Comment: But when i print `itemmodel` it has values, it is like converting into json string is not working

Comment: @AleksaRistic When you execute `toJson` does it output the correct JSON? If so, after you save it, and retrieve it does it still show the same JSON?

Comment: Look at edited question, i added whole class so you can see what have i done and after `Debug.Log` you have comments on what it displays

Comment: @AleksaRistic You must decorate your model with `[System.Serializable]` that's why it's not serializing/deserializing. Take a look at the example I added in the answer, it has the decorator.

Comment: ... Thanks

I haven't read about it that much and forgot that problem may be for that. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @AleksaRistic Anytime, glad to help! GL with your game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148158/discussion-between-aleksa-ristic-and-dayan).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sqlite then you do not need to worry about how much data you store.

Comment: I read about it but isn't there any other way since i saw it is pretty tricky to set it up for c#

Comment: you can also use you device memory to keep data on txt  it will be harder for you.