# Unexpected binary element 255 when serializing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, binaryformatter

I'm using Unity 2017 and wish to serialize save game data like so:

```
public void Save(Statistics data)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath
         + "/playerInfo.dat");
    bf.Serialize(file, data);
    file.Close();
}
```

The `LevelData` class is marked `Serializable` and contains only `string`s and `int`s. The class that implements `IPersistentData` meets those requirements too.

I did look for the problem and found that I should set an environment variable in my `Awake` method that I did, but that didn't solve anything. I'm using *Windows 10* as operating system to develop on but the game will be made for *Android*.

When attempting to save, I always get this exception

> SerializationException: Unexpected binary element: 255
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadObject (BinaryElement element, System.IO.BinaryReader reader, System.Int64& objectId, System.Object& value, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo& info)

Any sort of advice is welcome to get around the issue.

**EDIT**

Updating after trying the hints of *Programmer*:
The class I wish to serialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class Statistics
{
    public int LastPlayedLevel;
    public Statistics()
    {
        MusicVolume = 1f;
        SFXVolume = 1f;
        LevelDatas = new List<LevelData>();
        LastPlayedLevel = 1;
    }
    public float MusicVolume;
    public float SFXVolume;
    public List<LevelData> LevelDatas;
}
```

And the `LevelData`:

```
[Serializable]
public class LevelData
{
    public LevelData(int levelNumber,string name)
    {
        this.LevelNumber = levelNumber;
        this.Name = name;
        this.BestPercent = 0;
        this.DeathCount = 0;
    }
    public int LevelNumber;
    public string Name;
    public int BestPercent;
    public uint DeathCount;
}
```

Comment: You **cannot** serialize interface or auto property in Unity. See [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/783456/solution-how-to-serialize-interfaces-generics-auto.html) post for workaround.

Comment: If I just use the class instead of the interface, would it work?

Comment: It should. Note that you have auto property. Last time I checked Unity couldn't serialize that so remove that. I mean the `{ get; set; }`....

Comment: ...
Seems like Unity fights anything that's even a bit related to OOP :/ 
I'll have to write a _for_save_only_ class then

Comment: I completely removed my interfaces and set classes inside alongside all my getters and setters in the class that's inside the `Serializable` class but still no luck. Is that a problem that the class I wish to serialize is a `ScriptableObject`?

Comment: @Programmer I updated the question but still no luck :/

Comment: Idk. Just try to serialize it without inheriting from `ScriptableObject`. By the way, it is very important to note that you **must** put each class you want to serialize in each **file**. For example, `LevelData` should be put in a file named `LevelData.cs` and `Statistics` should be put in a file called `Statistics.cs`. Unity won't let you serialize it without doing this.

Comment: Those are good hints. Yes, I did put all the classes on separate files (1 class 1 file) for those, and I removed the `ScriptableObject` inheritance but still no luck :(
Do you think I should try XML or JSON?

Comment: See [saving data wit json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965645/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-game-state/40966346#40966346). It also talked about this problem you  are having and why `BinaryFormatter` should not be used.

Comment: True that I found this BinaryFormatter in a Unity tutorial from 2014 :/ I should have been more picky.

Comment: @Programmer I just got back to try json. But before I start, can I save interfaces and auto props with json? I looked for it but didn't find anything that would indicate it shouldn't.

Comment: You can't save auto props with json. I haven't tried with interfaces so you have to try that yourself.

Comment: Well a prop in an interface looks like e.g. `float MyProp {get;set;}` so I think that won't do. Or I just use fields in that iface. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Just remove the `{get;set;}`.

Comment: @Programmer thought I let you know that your answer regarding `json` worked flawlessly (I used the class as I didn't have the patience to re-write the interface I deleted). If you wish to write an answer so I can accept/upvote please do so.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. It's ok because if I put an answer it won't really answer the question in the title of this question. Happy coding!

Comment: @Programmer Thats how its fixed for me after removing get and set. thanks:))