# c# can't access list elements - Argument is out of range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use list for the first time :-)
I have the list defined in a class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor; 
using System; //This allows the IComparable Interface
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Words : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<string> wordslist = new List<string>();
    static void WriteString()
    {
        string path = "Assets/Resources/words.txt";

        //Write some text to the test.txt file
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        writer.WriteLine("Test");
        writer.Close();

        //Re-import the file to update the reference in the editor
        AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(path); 
        TextAsset asset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("words");

        //Print the text from the file
        Debug.Log(asset.text);
    }

    static void ReadString()
    {
        string text = " ";
        string path = "Assets/Resources/words.txt";

        //List<WordsList> wordslist = new List<WordsList>();
        int ix = 1;

        //Read the text from directly from the test.txt file
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path); 
        while(text != null){
            text = reader.ReadLine();
            if (text != null) {
                wordslist.Add (text);
                ix++;
                Debug.Log (wordslist[ix].ToString());
            }
        }
        //Debug.Log (reader.ReadToEnd ().Length);
        //Debug.Log(reader.ReadToEnd());
        reader.Close();
    }

    public void GetWord(){
         ReadString ();
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I am trying to add words from a text file in to the list and display the list in the console.
the reading fails:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: index

I am trying to access the list because I want to add code to select a random word from the list after this works

I am having trouble defining it correctly and reading the values after the Add function. I didn't try the WriteString yet, in case you see something wrong there too

Comment: Try put the increment like this :
                Debug.Log (wordslist[ix].ToString()); ix++;

Comment: You're trying to access a non-static field within a static method.

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem but I just want to point to you to a big **future** problem. This code will not work in a build. If it does in a Windows build, it will **never** work on mobile build. You **cannot** write to the  Resources folder because it is read-on. You can read/write to `Application.persistentDataPath/YourFolder` path which works on all platforms. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966346/3785314) for example.

Answer (score 1):

All indexes start with 0 not 1, so replace

```
int ix = 1;
```

with

```
int ix = 0;
```

and move the `ix++;` to the very last line in the `while`-loop, so after:

```
Debug.Log (wordslist[ix]);
ix++;
```

Comment: thanks, but  the problem still exists.  also I have Assets/Scripts/Words.cs(41,33): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `Words.wordslist'

Comment: @DanielBen-Shabtay: have you also moved the `ix++` after the line where you use it? Otherwise it will be 1 and if you only have one item that causes the exception because `wordslist[1]` accesses the second item

Comment: @DanielBen-Shabtay: and you have also started with 0 not 1?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want you `ReadString` and `WriteString` methods to be static? Having static methods means they are not tied to an instance of your `Words` class meaning you cannot use the field `wordslist` as this belongs to an instance of your `Words` class.

You could pass the instance of `wordslist` as a parameter to the `ReadString` instead.

Comment: I don't mind passing the wordslist as a parameter to ReadString and WriteString.  All I need is to be able to read the text file to the list, select a random word.  I am not sure I will need the WriteString, I've just copied it from the sample just in case I need it

Comment: I mean if this method is only going to be called for the purpose of this class it may as well be non-static and forgo the extra parameter.