# Continues to play audio in different scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

In my Unity Project, there are different menus, and each menu is a different scene. Each scene has button for controlling the music.

```
public void musicToggle(GameObject Off){
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Music") == 1) {
            musicPlayer.Stop ();
            Debug.Log ("Stop 2");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Music", 0);
            Off.SetActive(true);
        }
        else {
            musicPlayer.Play ();
            Debug.Log ("Play 2");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Music", 1);
            Off.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
```

This is my musicToogle function. In every scene the music restarts, and in every scene when I want to turn on/off the music, I click a button which deploys this code. However, I don't want the music to restart every scene change, I want it to resume, and I want to be able to control the music(turn on/off) in every scene. How can I do this ?

Comment: How and where is the `musicToggle` being called from?

Comment: It's attached to a button, when I click the button, the code kicks in. It's called from a button.

Comment: Do you have a different audio source in each scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer assumes that `musicPlayer` variable is a type of [`AudioSource`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html).

There are really two ways to do this:

**1**.Instead of using `musicPlayer.Stop` to stop the music,

Use `musicPlayer.Pause();` to pause then music then use  `musicPlayer.UnPause();` to un-pause it. This will make sure that the music resumes instead of  restarting it.

In this case, you use `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);` on each GameObject with the `AudioSource` so that they are not destroyed when you are on the next scene.

---

**2**.Store the `AudioSource.time` value. Load it next time then apply it to the `AudioSource` before playing it.

You can use `PlayerPrefs` to do this but I prefer to store with json and the [`DataSaver`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965645/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-game-state/40966346#40966346) class.

**Save**:

```
AudioSource musicPlayer;
AudioStatus aStat = new AudioStatus(musicPlayer.time);
//Save data from AudioStatus to a file named audioStat_1
DataSaver.saveData(aStat, "audioStat_1");
```

**Load**:

```
AudioSource musicPlayer;
AudioStatus loadedData = DataSaver.loadData<AudioStatus>("audioStat_1");
if (loadedData == null)
{
    return;
}
musicPlayer.time = loadedData.audioTime;
musicPlayer.Play();
```

---

Your `AudioStatus` class:

```
[Serializable]
public class AudioStatus
{

    public float audioTime;

    public AudioStatus(float currentTime)
    {
        audioTime = currentTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a singleton class and instantiate it on your first scene, then you can pass it around your various scenes as described in this unity answer: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/12176/view.html