# Yarnspinner: saving and loading dialogue state

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, loading, hadoop-yarn

My team is using [Yarnspinner](https://thesecretlab.github.io/YarnSpinner/html/index.html) in Unity to create a text-based game, visual novel style. It works pretty much perfectly, but we're having trouble figuring out how to save and load the dialogue state in the game. It doesn't seem that saving the game state "normally" will properly save the dialogue state.

I've done a lot of research but have found little documentation on how to do this. Given that Yarnspinner is an overall improvement on previous Yarn parsing, I feel like there is likely a built in function somewhere that does this, but I haven't been able to find anything. Does anyone know how to do this, or know any online resources that describe this?

Comment: I have not use Yarnspinner before. Where/which class is the dialogue stored?

Comment: @Programmer It is stored in this class https://thesecretlab.github.io/YarnSpinner/html/a00288_source.html

Comment: You can serialize the `DefaultVariable` class, save its instances and load them next time. I made a wrapper for that. You can check it out [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965645/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-game-state/40966346#40966346)

Comment: The problem isn't saving variables. The problem is saving the current state of the dialogue that is running