# Getting error while trying to serialize int

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I am trying to serialize my integer but i get the following error:

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

`SaveLoad.Load()` (at Assets/SaveLoad.cs:24) refers to another
script that just loads it on awake `loadgame.Awake()` (at
Assets/loadgame.cs:8) refers to

```
StatContainer.totalcoins = (int)bf.Deserialize(file);
```

I am new to data serialization can someone explain where my mistake is ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary; 
using System.IO;

public static class SaveLoad {
//public static List<StatContainer> savedGames = new List<StatContainer>();

//it's static so we can call it from anywhere
public static void Save() {
    //SaveLoad.savedGames.Add(StatContainer.current);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    //Application.persistentDataPath is a string, so if you wanted you can put that into debug.log if you want to know where save games are located
    FileStream file = File.Create (Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd"); //you can call it anything you want
    bf.Serialize(file, StatContainer.current);
    file.Close();
}   

public static void Load() {
    if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd")) {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd", FileMode.Open);
        StatContainer.totalcoins = (int)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
        Debug.Log ("Loaded");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you label the lines that the errors refer to?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Done !

Comment: If you are getting null use int? instead of int.

Comment: What is `StatsContainer.current`? Was the save file created using *this* save code or is it left over from a prior attempt (that saved different data?).

Comment: Have a look at [better way to load and save game state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966346/4366237)

Answer (score 0):

Call `Debug.Log(bf.Deserialize(file));` to see what kind of object it's returning, because it's obviously not an int.