# How can i save and load Anchorpoints using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

Every time I make the Select gesture, a new instance of the Cube prefab is created and placed in the Room. I would like to save the position of all the instances for example every 10 seconds. Furthermore I would like to load the saved instances when the app restarts.

I created a C# skript attached to the MainCamera with the following Content that i found on the Unity manual site https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-persistence.html. I do not know if that is more or less the right way or if its completly the wrong idea. [the content of the LoadSave skript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV2VV.png)

I am completly new to unity and mixedreality and would be very thankfull if someone could help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to save game state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965645/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-game-state) Saving on the hololens is pretty much the same as any other device.

Comment: Did you have any specific problems when using Anchor Persistence function? 
At the moment it looks like you are in the right direction. Besides, you can also refer this document for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/persistence-in-unity