# How to modify a game scene using a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a custom level editor in unity in play mode, I have already done enough, but now I would like to save all this in order to download it later. I found an option using BinaryWritter, but as I understand it, this is suitable if you want to save something simple enough. My objects have varying degrees of nesting and they have internal components to work with them. Is there some simple way to save a new scene of a scene created through code? Or the option that I manually create a scene in advance and change it in Play mode in every possible way, and then save it? It seems to me that the decision to save scene objects by parsing their values into a certain text file json/xml/ plain text file looks at least bad and too difficult for such, as it seems to me, an ordinary task.

Comment: You are just asking for the moon. Here are some relevant questions: [Saving/Loading is never simple.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/save-system-questions.930366/#post-6087384), [What is the best way to save game state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965645/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-game-state)

Comment: I suggest not doing the editor while in play mode.  If you must do it in play mode, you could prefab the contents before exiting play mode, and then drag that into an empty scene.  It would be better to save the instructions of generating the level rather than the level itself, if you want to go the json/xml/etc route.  Or maybe you meant at runtime not in play mode?  Some clarification needed there.