# How to save bool to PlayerPrefs Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, payment

I have a payment system for my game set up here's my code :

```
 void Start()
 {
     T55.interactable = false;
     Tiger2.interactable = false;
     Cobra.interactable = false;
 }

 public void ProcessPurchase (ShopItem item)
 {
     if(item .SKU =="tank")
     {
         StoreHandler .Instance .Consume (item );
     }
 }

 public void OnConsumeFinished (ShopItem item)
 {
     if(item .SKU =="tank")
     {
         T55.interactable = true;
         Tiger2.interactable = true;
         Cobra.interactable = true;
     }
 }
```

Now each time the player buy something in the game the intractability of my 3 buttons goes to true; but the problem is each time he closes the game the intractability goes back to false how.

Should I save the process so the player doesn't have to buy again to set them back to true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) does not have an overload for a boolean type. It only supports string, int and float.

You need to make a function that converts `true` to `1` and `false` to `0` then the the `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` and `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` overload that takes `int` type.

Something like this:

```
int boolToInt(bool val)
{
    if (val)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

bool intToBool(int val)
{
    if (val != 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now, you can easily save `bool` to `PlayerPrefs`.

```
void saveData()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("T55", boolToInt(T55.interactable));
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Tiger2", boolToInt(T55.interactable));
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Cobra", boolToInt(T55.interactable));
}

void loadData()
{
    T55.interactable = intToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("T55", 0));
    Tiger2.interactable = intToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Tiger2", 0));
    Cobra.interactable = intToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Cobra", 0));
}
```

If you have many variables to save, use Json and PlayerPrefs instead of saving and loading them individually. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40097623/3785314) is how to do that.

Comment: @ArashDevil Anytime!

Answer (score 4):

This is much faster

```
var foo = true;
// Save boolean using PlayerPrefs
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("foo", foo?1:0);
// Get boolean using PlayerPrefs
foo = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("foo")==1?true:false;
```

Source from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/playerprefs-setbool-and-playerprefs-getbool.12795/)

Answer (score 1):

I write this answer because there are people who need this answer yet, and I think is even easier than the others above.

To save:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Mute_FX", mute ? 1 : 0);
```

To load:

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Mute_FX") == 1 ? true : false;
```

If you don't understand what's happening, I recommend you read about ternary operator in C#.

Edit: I didn't see Mohamed Saleh answer, but it's the same.

Comment: Your second line of code does not need the conditional operator.  You can just use:  `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Mute_FX") == 1`

Answer (score 0):

Writing:

```
bool val = true;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PropName", val ? 1 : 0);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Reading:

```
bool val = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PropName") == 1 ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also smooth

```
private int BoolToInt(bool val)
{
    return val ? 1 : 0;
}

private bool IntToBool(int val)
{
    return val == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why someone didn't suggest a wrapper since this would be a much cleaner way to extend PlayerPrefs.

```cs
public class PlayerPrefsWrapper : PlayerPrefs
{
    public static void SetBool(string key, bool value)
    {
        SetInt(key, value ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public static bool GetBool(string key)
    {
        return GetInt(key) == 1;
    }
}
```

using this you can write

```cs
using PlayerPrefs = PlayerPrefsWrapper;

PlayerPrefs.SetBool("key",true);
bool value = PlayerPrefs.GetBool("key");
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, it only needs the default value when they key doesn't exist.

Comment: @OscarLeif It doesn't "need" it. If the key doesn't exist it will simply return "default value" which in this case will be 0. Unless of course that is undesired behaviour. You can create an override or an additional default initialized parameter for the default value, but I think that's beyond the purview of the question.