# How to load the game, where many scenes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game on Unity3d I have many scenes a now I work on the save/load game. I can save the game, but if I want to load it, I need to load scene, which I need, then load all other parameters.

Or should I load all parameters first, save it with `DontDestroyOnLoad()` and then load scene, which I need?

[image]

```
public void ButtonSave()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("transform position x" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.position.x);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("task 1 completed" + currentActiveSlot, isTask1Completed);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("latestSaveSlot", latestSaveSlot);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("act number" + currentActiveSlot, 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("step number" + currentActiveSlot, 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("sceneName" + currentActiveSlot, SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);        
    PlayerPrefs.Save();        
}

public void ButtonLoad()
{
    playerTransform.position = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform position x" + currentActiveSlot),
                                           PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform position y" + currentActiveSlot),
                                           PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform position z" + currentActiveSlot));

    isTask1Completed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("task 1 completed" + currentActiveSlot);

    //gameManager.currentActNumber = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("act number" + currentActiveSlot);
    //act_2.stepNumber = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("step number" + currentActiveSlot);
    //SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetString("sceneName" + currentActiveSlot));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to load the scene first with `SceneManager.LoadScene` then load the Player settings with your `PlayerPrefs` code.

```
public void ButtonLoad()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetString("sceneName" + currentActiveSlot));
    playerTransform.position = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform position x" + currentActiveSlot),
                                           PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform position y" + currentActiveSlot),
                                           PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform position z" + currentActiveSlot));

    isTask1Completed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("task 1 completed" + currentActiveSlot);
}
```

Not a good idea to save the variables invidually. You can see the proper way of saving and loading scenes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40097623/3785314).

EDIT:

> But in my case after loading scene, would other part of the method
>   execute?

Yes/No.

After `SceneManager.LoadScene` is called, the rest of the code in that function will execute but the execution will be done in the-same scene **not** in the newly loaded scene. *Because of this, you will lose the player settings you just loaded.*

So, I don't think that will be useful to you. Put the Player Settings code in the `Awake` or `Start` function to automatically load the Player Settings after loading the scene.

```
public void ButtonLoad()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetString("sceneName" + currentActiveSlot));
}

void Awake()
{
    isTask1Completed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("task 1 completed" + currentActiveSlot);
    //...other PlayerPrefs.GetInt code
}
```

Comment: But in my case after loading scene, would other part of the method execute?

Comment: After loading the scene, you are suppose to place your loading code in the `Awake` or `Start` function. So move `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` to the `Awake` or `Start` function.