# Save game when exiting app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game with unity C#. I have code a save local and save cloud for the game. I make a button exit when pressed the game is saved and then exit.

But i have a problem in here saved game. When someone or player press the home button which on device mobile the game will exit and run in background.

If the player restart the device the game that run in background will not saved to local or cloud. This is the problem.

**So in unity when home button pressed at device mobile what will unity do ? It is pause the application / game or whatever ?
What can we do in unity if the player press the home button ?**

***If it pause the application / game could we detect it first when the player press the home button we could do saving the game ? ( i mean run a code after the button home is pressed )***

Or any idea from your experience what will do if player press home button ? This is for the player to not lose the game data.

Please give the detail for me to find the solution.

Any help would be amazing for continue the game :)

Thanks

Dennis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So in unity when home button pressed at device mobile what will unity
>   do ?

Unity does not control this. The OS does. You did not mention which OS (Android or iOS) but you can research what happens when the home button is pressed for each one.

What I can tell you is that the app is suspended for a while on Android. Sometimes, the assets are unloaded by Android. This depends on many factors such as how long the app has been suspended, how many apps are open and the memory available on the device.

*You can't depend on the OS to handle this. You must handle it yourself.*

> If it pause the application / game could we detect it first when the
>   player press the home button we could do saving the game ?

Yes and No.

You should **not** detect when the Home Button is pressed in order to do something. You *should* however detect when the Game is paused and resumed.

This is what the [`OnApplicationPause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) function is used for. Another similar function is [`OnApplicationFocus`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html) but [`OnApplicationPause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) is more approprite for this.

When `OnApplicationPause( bool pauseStatus )` is called when the Home Button is pressed, the `pauseStatus` parameter is `true`. When the app is re-opened, pauseStatus parameter is `false`.

> This is for the player to not lose the game data

You [save](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40078490/3785314) and [load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40078490/3785314) the data depending on pauseStatus value.

Here is what to do:

```
void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
{
    if (pauseStatus)
    {
        Debug.Log("Paused");
        //Save Player Settings
        //https://stackoverflow.com/q/40078490/3785314
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("resumed");
        //Load Player Settings
        //https://stackoverflow.com/q/40078490/3785314
    }
}
```

Comment: Very happy to see someone post the answer :) This must be solve the problem.

Comment: Let me know if there is a problem.

Comment: Hi @Programmer would you mind help me figure out this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/41787461/6786634

Comment: I have't used *gamesparks* before but [here](https://docs.gamesparks.com/tutorials/real-time-services/real-time-matchmaking.html) is their tutorial for Unity.

Comment: OnApplicationPause() is not safe.  Add an auto-save feature that saves on a timer and/or key events.

Comment: I implemented both functions `OnApplicationFocus` and `OnApplicationPause` as depending on the platform iOS & Android, whichever function is called first I save my data in Firebase which has a callback. I wrote debug statements, save function is called, but callback isn't called. As it seems those functions get CPU cycle only once. So any other solution? As I tried a lot of stuff, but none is effective/working