# How to save the minimum time taken in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, save

I am making a maze game in unity 3d where the least time taken to complete the level is the highscore. Is there a way to save the highscore using Playerprefs? Scripting is done in C#.

Comment: So to reduce your question to the essential: [Saving/loading data in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078490/saving-loading-data-in-unity) or [How to use `PlayerPrefs` - Official tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6FfcJpbPXE&t=435s)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it easier using Get/Set Assessors.

```
public class GameManager: MonoBehavior {
    ...
    public float HighScore {
        get {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HIGHSCORE", 0);
        }
        set {
            if(value > HighScore) {
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HIGHSCORE", value);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    public void GameOver() {
        HighScore = currentScore;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first put this check in your **homescript in awake function**:

```
   if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighestScore"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("HighestScore", "keep some big number");
        }
```

Or **alternatively** can use **(Preferably)**

```
if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighestScore"))
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighestScore", 100000f);
            }
```

Then when the particular level ends and you need to save the score 
Compare the existing PlayerPref with the current Player score.

For example for float

```
if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighestScore")>=current_score)
{
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighestScore",current_score);
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I got the answer! Just needed to check if the first round had already taken place or not.

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{



    HighScore = score;



    WinScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore").ToString();



}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore") == 0f)
    {

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", (float)HighScore);
        WinScore.text = HighScore.ToString();


    }

    if (HighScore < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore")){ 

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScoreEasy", (float)HighScore);
        WinScore.text = HighScore.ToString();


    }

}
```